# FxFill doesn't work as expected with 5.0.0-beta.14 update

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

After updating @angular/flex-layout to the most recent 5.0.0-beta.14 version, the [fxFill API](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlexFill-API) no longer works as expected.

[Expected behavior using 5.0.0-beta.13 (StackBlitz)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fxfill-test)

[Current behavior using 5.0.0-beta.14 (StackBlitz)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fxfill-test-suw9ph)

The 2 StackBlitz are identical, with the exception of the version of flex-layout.

If you inspect the page, the elements with `fxFill` applied to them have the inline styles that they're supposed to: `margin 0`, `width 100%`, `height 100%`, `min-width 100%`, and `min-height 100%`, but the styles don't seem to be applied?

I've been looking through their documentation, and can't find why this would be the case. Is this the new expected behavior? Or is there something I need to change in the second example to get fxFill to work the way it did in beta.13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why the change was made but flex was changed from "1e-09px" to "auto" ... this looks to appears to allow a child to grow bigger than the max.

The below is a temp fix to role this back, but I think they need to change it back.

```
/deep/ [fxflex] {
  flex: 1 1 1e-09px !important;
}
```